# How to write a sql query to fetch data from DB on the basis of timestamp

Tags: date, datetime, derby

I have a task to do in which i have to write a query which can fetch the data on the basis of timestamp

1. I have a `table` in my database which has two column
2. one is  `Entries`for the entries and other one is TimeStamp for `TimeStamp`
3. i am saving the data from client end into my db with `TimeStamp`
4. Now i want to write a query which should give me all the entries of last `30 seconds`
5. I want to display it to client side so i want to write a query by which i can have the data of last `30-0 seconds`

i don't have any idea about that like how can i achieve that.. anyone out here please help

[image: This is my database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the time portion from the datetime column, generate the current time - 30 second value and compare:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE CAST(TimeStamp AS TIME) >= SUBTIME(CURRENT_TIME, '00:00:30')
AND   CAST(TimeStamp AS TIME) <= CURRENT_TIME
```

Comment: can you help me with full query..as i have posted the database values..these are only two fields currently and non-of these is primary as this is for testing purpose

Comment: This is the full query... replace `t` with your table name

Comment: sir i am using sql 5.1 it is showing  error as `DATEADD does not exist`

Comment: Please learn to tag your question properly. I have changed it for MySQL 5.1

Comment: ok sir ..let me try this one..sir is it going to give me the entries of last 30 seconds?